# How to split a JSON object into an array

Tags: javascript, json

I've got a JSON object that looks like this

```
Key1      = Value1
Key2      = Value2
```

This pattern continues x times, always

- KeyName
- Unknown length of whitespace
- = character
- Value
- New line

If I JSON.Stringify I get

```
Key1      = Value1\nKey2     = Value2\nKey3      = Value3\n
```

How can I get an object along the lines of

```
{"Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2", "Key3":"Value3"}
```

Comment: Your desired output of `{"Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2", "Key3":"Value3"}` is an object, not an array.

Comment: the starting 'json object' doesn't look like a json object, a json object looks like what you are trying to get.

Comment: can you post the entire json object you are starting with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy to parse with a regular expression. Match and capture non-spaces, match a `=`, then match and capture anything up to the end of the line:

```js
const str = `Key1      = Value1
Key2      = Value2`;
const obj = {};
for (const [, key, val] of str.matchAll(/(\S+) *= *(\S.*)$/gm)) {
  obj[key] = val;
}
console.log(obj);
```

Another method along the same lines, but without the mutation of the `obj` inside the loop:

```js
const str = `Key1      = Value1
Key2      = Value2`;
const obj = Object.fromEntries(
  [...str.matchAll(/(\S+) *= *(\S.*)$/gm)]
    .map(([, key, val]) => [key, val])
);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Op needs an array not an object?

Comment: `{"Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2", "Key3":"Value3"}` is an object.

Comment: yes, but he is asking for an array..if that really what he needs.

Comment: Why are you using `.replace`? Use the `Object.fromEntries` version and it will give you an object in return. Then you can use dot notation to look up stuff on the object, eg `console.log(obj.Key1)` will result in `Value1` being logged.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an easy way to do it

```
obj = {};
pairs = your_file_string.split(/\r?\n/);
for ( idx in pairs ) {
    if ( !pairs[idx] ) continue;
    pair = pairs[idx].split(/\s*=\s*/);
    obj[pair[0]] = pair[1];
}
```

you end up with an object `obj` which then you can present as json text with `JSON.stringify` or from text back to object with `JSON.parse`